# Updating Firebase RecyclerviewAdapter won't delete previous list

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am bulding app which monitors crypto currencies, I am using firebase UI, and everything worked fine, until I tryed to update the adapter (Firebase doesnt support client side Filtering) and I am adding "Search" feature. I am getting the updated value, but my data moves below previous recyclerview listings (which ones becomes invisible, but takes space). I think I am missing some kind of "Clear recyclerview" function.
BTW. I am using this in Fragment. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

```
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));


    @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            Log.i(TAG,newText);

            Query ref1 = FirebaseRef.getDatabase().child("Coins");

            mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Coins, CoinsViewHolder>(Coins.class, R.layout.coins_card, CoinsViewHolder.class,
                    ref1.orderByChild("short").startAt(newText).endAt("~").limitToFirst(3)) {
                @Override
                public void populateViewHolder(CoinsViewHolder coinsViewHolder, Coins coinsData, int position) {

                    if(coinsData.getName() != null){
                        coinsViewHolder.setmNameTextView(coinsData.getName());

                    }

                    if(coinsData.getPrice() != null) {
                        coinsViewHolder.setmPriceTextView(coinsData.getPrice());
                    } else if(coinsData.getCap24hrChange() != null){
                        coinsViewHolder.setmPercentChangeTextView(coinsData.getCap24hrChange());}

                    coinsViewHolder.bind(coinsData);

                }
            };

            mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MaterialViewPagerHeaderDecorator());
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            MaterialViewPagerHelper.registerRecyclerView(getActivity(), mRecyclerView);


            return true;
        }
    });

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you are setting the adapter every time text is added. move the adapter initialization in oncreate and then only update the firebase query on text change.

if you want to load only fresh data from database to recycler view, clear the list holding the data for the adapter and call then add new data and call `notify dataset changed`.

Comment: thanks for quick response, but could you share how to update query from the onCreateOptionsMenu while it is in OnCreate? :)

Comment: the issue is that in your use case you cannot directly use the FirebaseUI recycler adapter, since you have to continuously change your query you have to use your own recycler adapter. The UI adapter is good for use cases like chat app where the changes are shown in the recycler

Comment: I created public ref instance, and moved adapter to onCreate, but when I change ref1 value adapter won't change. So I really should quit trying to use Firebase's adapter? :/

Comment: my suggestion would be to go for your own implementation, it will allow you to control the query and add remove listeners on query. firebase listener is more limited to static query.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java see how it implements the adapter you will know the limitations

Comment: Allright, I will try implement my own adapter, but before that could you help me how to change Queries ref value which is in OnCreate now from the OnCreateOptionMenu? Any ideas? Because making a single public instance does not help me :/

Comment: you can create a new query every time you need to change the reference value, there is no other way, but you can use a global variable to store the query in it, incase you need current query some where in the activity.

Comment: just don't create recycler adapter every time.